# why the accept method of socket in python fails to exit

Tags: python, sockets

I try to use a code that utilizes the socket in python in jupyter notebook. But It does not stop when asking 
client_socket.accept()

```
client_socket = socket.socket()     
client_socket.bind(('localhost', 9878))  
client_socket.listen()
```

when connection received, get connection/client address

> connection, address = client_socket.accept()

Comment: Do you receive any errors when you call `accept`? Can you show what you try to do with `connection` and `address` afterwards?

Comment: Please edit the code in your question as a [mre] - otherwise no-one can easily recreate the problem you are seeing. I should be able to paste your code into a file and __without adding anything else__ reproduce the problem. Sometimes the work to produce a [mre] helps you solve the ‘problem’ yourself.

Comment: This is not a client socket. It is a server socket, or a listening socket. This code will unblock when a client connects. You should bind to 0.0.0.0, not `localhost`, unless you only want to accept connections from the same host.

Comment: I try to stream tweets to a socket, then use spark streaming to read the hashtag sent via the socket and summarize the results.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that it was waiting for the spark application. When I run the spark application it was connected and took the corresponding messages from tweeter.